# Query filter must be a plain object or ObjectId in mongo cosmosdb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I have a query function like:

```
const DATABASE_COLLECTION_NAME = "users";
let mongoConnection = null;
let db = null;

const findDocuments = async(value) => {
    console.log("this is value: ", value)
    // response is: "clientId": "e0bb610d-05d4-4df1-8ab8-5a009ec953ef"
    // but after I put it in below query
    const query = { value };
    console.log("this is query: ", query)
    // response is: { value: '"clientId": "e0bb610d-05d4-4df1-8ab8-5a009ec953ef"' }
    if (!db)
        throw Error('findDocuments::missing required params');
    const collection = await db.collection(DATABASE_COLLECTION_NAME );
    return await collection.find(query).toArray();
};
```

As comment above I don't know why it's convert to like this When I put it in query variable, so that is the reason I can not query data from Mongo cosmosDb

```
{ value: '"clientId": "e0bb610d-05d4-4df1-8ab8-5a009ec953ef"' }
```

I just wanna be like this

```
{ "clientId": "e0bb610d-05d4-4df1-8ab8-5a009ec953ef" }
```

I have try this function to get that json object correctly:

```
const valueJSON = JSON.parse("{" + query.value + "}")
```

but the result is: `{ clientId: 'e0bb610d-05d4-4df1-8ab8-5a009ec953ef' }`

not like this: `{ "clientId": "e0bb610d-05d4-4df1-8ab8-5a009ec953ef" }`